# Persist Data-URL into database

Tags: javascript, sql, web-applications, blob

I am getting images encoded as Data-URLs from a third party in javascript. I need to persist this images on my server.

As I see it I have two options:

- Converting the Data-URLs into Blobs, and save them into my database. And when I use them in my html code convert them into Data-URLs again
- Converting the Data-URL into actual images, save them on my Server and save the reference in my database

Are there any other options and what would be the better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images stored as physical files are better because:

1. they can be cached, unlike data-blobs that are always part of the HTML output
2. because they are part of the HTML output and in base 64, it needlessly increases your file size (as well as your processing power used if you have gzip compression enabled like you should)

Images stored as data-blobs are better because:

- you need an excuse to upgrade your hardware and networking setup, so increasing the load works out perfectly! Also look into `Thread.Sleep` or your language's equivalent.
- you can later switch to normal images with a CDN system and claim you improved your software, thus should get a raise

Comment: Legitimately good